# DataSource to configure a view with mulitple firebase calls

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, model-view-controller, swift4

I have a view that I am using a DataSource in to configure the view. The dataSource takes data from two separate firebase calls, `getA` and `getBCD`. However, since the firebase calls are async, I set the `View.DataSource` in the didSet for the BCD, but can't figure out how I would set the DataSource for A with the info from BCD. Would the better way to do it be to create two separate dataSources with separate inits so the view configuration does not depend on which Firebase call comes back first? Or use `group.notify`?

Relevant lines of code for ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private var BCDDictionary = [String:Int]() {
    didSet {
        let B = BCDDictionary["B"]
        let C = BCDDictionary["C"]
        let D = BCDDictionary["D"]
        self.AView.dataSource = AView.DataSource(A:10, B:B, C:C, D:D)
        // A is hardcoded currently
    }
}

private var A: Int

override init() {

    super.init()

    _ = FirebaseAPI.shared.getA { [weak self] result  in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .success(let A):
                self?.A = A
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    _ = FirebaseAPI.shared.getBCD(completion: {[weak self] result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .success(let BCD):
                self?.BCDDictionary = (self?.countBCD(BCD: BCD))!
                // Turns BCD into the proper dictionary
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Relevant lines of code for View:

```
final class AView: UIView {

    struct DataSource {
        let numberOfA: Int
        let numberOfB: Int
        let numberOfC: Int
        let numberOfD: Int
    }

    var dataSource: DataSource? {
        didSet {
            self.numberOfALabel.text = String(self.dataSource!.numberOfA)
            self.numberOfBLabel.text = String(self.dataSource!.numberOfB)
            self.numberOfCLabel.text = String(self.dataSource!.numberOfC)
            self.numberOfDLabel.text = String(self.dataSource!.numberOfD)
        }
    }
}

extension AView.DataSource {

    init(A: Int, B: Int, C: Int, D: Int) {
        self.numberOfA = A
        self.numberOfB = B
        self.numberOfC = C
        self.numberOfD = D
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is 2 asynchronous tasks , and the dataSource should be initated by them at the same time , then the best choice is

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
```

Comment: And then you would just set the dataSource in group.notify()?